# openpyxl unreadable content

Tags: xml, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

When using openpyxl, if i update the style of cell like this:

```
wb  = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
a1 = ws['a1']
al.value = 'Hello World!'
a1.style.font.name = 'Algerian'
```

Opening the file in Excel gives an error:

'Excel found unreadable content...'

Log file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">

<logFileName>error107840_01.xml</logFileName>

<summary>Errors were detected in file 'D:\Phocas\Phocas-Automation\test.xlsx'</summary>


-<removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:">

<removedRecord>Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord>

</removedRecords>

</recoveryLog>
```

The cell shows the correct style (font.name = Algerian) but the error message is undesirable when distributing the file to users. This is also just an example, i get the same problem if i try something like:

```
a1.style.font.bold = True
```

Is there some other way to update the cell style other than directly updating the attribute in the class instance?

When i read the docs at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html it says to use:

```
ft = Font(color=colors.RED)
a1.font = ft
```

but that gives me an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'font'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say anything about the file without seeing but feel free to submit a bug report with a sample file and script that creates it. If you are editing an existing file the error is almost certainly related to something not being preserved by openpyxl.

However, the fact that `cell.font = Font(…)` doesn't work suggests that you have a fairly old version of the library. I suggest you update to 2.3-b2 it with `pip install -U --pre`

Comment: Yeh realised i had a way old version and updated to latest, working now! thanks.